# How can I see the branches merged into master in remote server, pushed by certain developer?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge, git-bash

```
$ git branch -r --merged master
```

The command lists remote branches merged into `master`, but does not tell you to whom they are belong.
Say, another developer called Michael pushes some branches and they are merged into the branch `master` in the remote server. Would Jude be able to see the branches, which were pushed by Michael, merged into master in the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

A branch that is pushed to a repo at the remote server is available to everyone that have access to that repo, everyone can push to that branch and merge with other branches, git does not enforce any restrictions. Some git service providers (i.e. Bitbucket) can enforce some privacy to repos and branches, but that is part of their service not git in general.

**EDIT:**

This will give the commit that represents the last merge in "master"

```
git log -1 $(git branch -r --merged master| awk '{print $2}')
```

(this is a script for linux, you may need to adopt it for your OS)

Comment: Right. But not the answer.